# How to implement SIGWINCH handler in ncurses?

Tags: signals, ncurses, window-resize

If I define my own SIGWINCH signal handler, getmaxyx won't work (ie it will not report updated values). It will work if I call endwin() but this results in flickering (eg shows the screen prior to starting ncurses).
Is there a way to avoid having to call endwin() or at least to avoid the above mentioned flickering?
Note that the default signal handler (in combination with checking KEY_RESIZE) works, but I was trying to avoid polling by repeated calls to getch.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make sure that you are calling the old signal handler set up by ncurses. This handler set the values returned by `getmaxyx`.